# Demultiplexing udp streams from different sources

Tags: sockets, udp

My server is using a single udp socket to receive udp streams from different ip addresses. (All senders send to the same port).
When recv returns on the server with a chunk of data, might that chunk contain bytes from different sources?
Assuming not, is there a reliable way to determine which sender sent that entire chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UDP, each chunk received will be exactly what a sender previously passed to ‘send()’ or ‘sendto()’ — unlike TCP, UDP maintains message boundaries.

You can find out the IP address and port the received packet was sent from by calling ‘recvfrom()’ instead of ‘recv()’.  Those values will be written into the ‘struct inaddr_in’ that you provide a pointer to.

Comment: Hi Jeremy my question about demultiplexing was answered by Alex F. Your comment however is interesting. What happens if the message is larger than the MTU or larger than the internal socket buffer at the receiver? Surely then the data read by recvfrom will not be a complete message? Are you saying that a read by recvfrom will never contain data from more than one packet but that it is possible that a message may be split into more than one recvfrom call? Can you point to the documentation on this?

Comment: I will ask this as a separate question

Comment: If the data passed to send() is greater than the MTU, the packet will be transparently fragmented by the sender, and (if all fragments make it to the receiving machine) transparently re-assembled by the receiver before it is passed to you.  (If any of the fragments don’t make it, they will all be silently dropped)

Comment: For UDP, the data passed to send() will match the data later returned by recv().

Comment: So please can you confirm the following: These are all the types of errors that may occur.
1. A message may be dropped entirely. To detect this I can implement my own strategy of sequence counting in the messages.
2. A message may be corrupted (values changed). To detect this I can implement my own strategy of error checking in the messages.
3. Some bytes of the message may have been dropped in this case the length returned from recvfrom() will be less than the expected message size (assuming I known what that should be). 
4. A socket error (All of the above are not socket errors).

Comment: Only (1) and (4) will be visible to your code; the others you listed will be handled transparently by the tcp stack (ie if there is a checksum mismatch the tcp stack will simply drop the udp packet rather than hand you corrupted data)